# inner product with scaling function

Tags: wavelets

$$
\int_0^1 sin(x)\phi(2^jx-k)dx
$$
Are there any software that can compute the above integral where $\phi(x)$ is scaling function of db3 (or dbN) family, j scaling parameter and k translation parameter.

Answer (score 1):

[PyWavelets](http://www.pybytes.com/pywavelets/) Python library is free and its documentation explicitly includes [db3 scaling function](http://wavelets.pybytes.com/wavelet/db3/). I did not dig deeper to find exactly what commands you would use for this particular computation.

And then there is a [Signal Processing](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) site where people deal with wavelets a lot more often than here. If you don't get what you need from PyWavelets, they may be able to help.

Comment: Thanks, i will look at pywavelets library and i appreciate any other suggestions.